# Call /oauth/token endpoint from method

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

Is it possible to call /oauth/token endpoint from method to receive access_token / refresh_token?

I need to accept username and password inside the controller and then get the access_token from oauth2 endpoint. What class is responsible for it?